# how to add a button value to edittext

Tags: android

l have 3 buttons and 1 edittext

```
   <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="1" />
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="2" />
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="3" />
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/display" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/result" />
```

when i click on android emulator *button 1* the text value of *1* should display in ***edittext*** how can do this

Comment: You didn't do your homework, did you? Go to Android API reference and check out `EditText` and `Button`.

Comment: identify the button id, based on set the text in edittext.

Comment: Why don't you put `onClickListener` on `button 1` so that when it's clicked `EditText` is set by its value ?

Answer (score 0):

you have a method button.getText() from which you can get the text of button 1 and then can update the edittext using edittext.setText() method

Comment: can u write the code, i searched but i wasnt successfull

Answer (score 0):

Just take the reference of that `button` from the `xml` layout file in your java file,the setOnClickListener() on it and override the method `onClick()` of the `onClickListener()`.In that `onClick` method just set The text of the `edittext` to the one you wish to add into it.See this [Android: How to set the contents of a Edit text from a Button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699729/android-how-to-set-the-contents-of-a-edit-text-from-a-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

```
final Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
final EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.display);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        e1.setText(b1.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

just copy paste this code it will surely work for you

Comment: when i click on 2nd and 3rd button its saying unfortunately app has stopped

Comment: create object for others button too like i created for button b1

just copy paste your error from log cat here how can i know that why app got crashed? we can resolve only by seeing logcat errors

Answer (score 0):

Its working.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button button = (Button)v;
    editText.setText(button.getText().toString());
}
```